# PHP not calling array for quiz

Tags: php

I just started setting up a quiz using PHP however I have run into a quick issue, the question is not calling the value specified in the array. For example it is saying:

Is the opposite of green

It is saying: What is opposite of on the color wheel?
And the color is missing between the of and on?

I have two separate files one contains the arrays:

```
<?php
$array['left'] = "green";
$array['right'] = "freed";
$array['up'] = "down";
?>
```

The other is the actual showing quiz:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Final Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("newquiz2.php");
 print("What is opposite of $left on the color wheel?<br>");
 print("<form action='newquiz2check.php' method='get'>\n");
 print("<input type='text' name='left'><br>\n");
 print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>");
 print("</form>\n\n\n");

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding:
    $left=@_GET["left"];
to the actual quiz page however it still returns the same result. Can anyone point out my error or something I am missing.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$left`  with `{$array['left']}`?

Comment: @infinitezero like this: $array['left']= $_GET["left"];   If so yes and it does not work.

Comment: You're creating the array `$array` with they keys `left`, `right` and `up`. Where does `$left` come from? You've never created a variable `$left`? If you want the value, you need to call the array and supply the key: `$array['left']`.

Comment: @Martin M I specifically mean in this line here `print("What is opposite of {$array['left']} on the color wheel?<br>");`

Comment: @infinitezero Technically you're right, but you're not helping anyone in the long run if you don't explain why and/or what they've done wrong.

Comment: I apologize. I thought the OP was just oblivious to his typo. Glad you offered the explanation though!

Comment: @infinitezero It's simply a matter of looking at how the OP codes. Normally you would write an array like `$array = array( "left" => "green", "right" => "freed");`. The way OP does it in combination with using `$left` and trying `$left=@_GET["left"];` shows a clear lack in knowledge about arrays and even PHP in general.

Comment: @icecub I am not righting my arrays like that because I prefer them the way I wrote and it is much easier to read as I will have a massive amount of data later on. Also I am doing the $left=@_GET["left"]; because I had created that left in that line: "What is opposite of $left on the color wheel?<br>"  and since it was a new variable that had nothing to do with the array I was then trying to assign it to the array

Comment: `@_GET["left"]` should be `$_GET["left"]`. And that's trying to get value out of the URL. Not from your array. If your visitors would go to _https://www.yourwebsite.com/quiz.php?left=green_, `$_GET["left"]` would contain the value green. If you want to get the value out of your array, you need to use `$left = $array['left'];`.

Comment: @icecub ah you are correct, I mixed things up I was looking at a previous quiz which I had created a very long time ago when I used PHP just for a single other quiz which used GET but after looking through it again I now realize I am not setting up the quiz in that way and I confused myself. I do need the GET though just not for getting the array and that comes later. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @infinitezero it wasn't a typo it was purposely placed which I explained just a couple comments back. I misunderstood the use of GET and such and confused myself a bit

Comment: @icecub also for future reference so I understand better why was my question down voted? I ask so in the future I can do things more correctly

Comment: @MartinM I didn't downvote your question. But the reason why people downvoted it is because your problem is caused by a "Simple typographical error". You could've easily solved this problem yourself by doing a little bit of research into PHP arrays. If you hold your mouse on the Downvote button, it states _"This question does not show any research efford; is unclear or not usefull"_. In your case it shows no research efford and because it's a simple typo error, the question is not usefull for future reference either. That's why it'll most likely be closed soon as well.

Comment: Don't be discouraged by a few downvotes or closed questions though. It's pretty normal for a beginner on Stack Overflow. You're still learning how SO works so it's perfectly fine to make some mistakes. I suggest you read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). That'll help you a lot in the future.